# js TouchEvent: when pinching with two fingers and lifting one of them up, how to kown which finger had lifted?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom, touch

i'am working in a complicated touching gesture, and meet this problem:

```
let cachedStartTouches: TouchList;
let cachedMoveTouches: TouchList;

function onStart(ev: TouchEvent) {
  // length equals 2 when two fingers pinch start
  cachedStartTouches = ev.touches;
}

function onMove(ev: TouchEvent) {
  // length equals 2 when two fingers pinching moving
  cachedMoveTouches = ev.touches; 
}

function onEnd(ev: TouchEvent) {
  // equals 1 when one finger holds up early, but another one still moving
  ev.touches.length

  // the cachedTouches's length is still two now,  
  // how to known which idx had been canceled, 0 or 1 ?
  const idx = getCanceledTouchesIdx(????)

  // remove it from cache
  cachedStartTouches.splice(idx, 1)
  cachedMoveTouches.splice(idx, 1)
}
```

more genral case: N fingers pinching, and lifting some of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TouchEvent has:

- `event.touches` with the list of currently active touches (still pressed fingers)
- and `event.changedTouches` with the list of touches that changed in this event

In the case of the `touch end` event this means that the ended touches can be read from the `event.changedTouches` list, while the remaining touches will be in the `event.touches` list.

Alternatively you can keep track of `event.touches` in `start` / `move` event handlers and see which touches disappear from the `event.touches` list in the `end` event handler.

*Side note: you can differentiate touches using `touch.identifier`*

---

It may be easier to work with touches if they were an array, so as a bonus here's my helper function:

```
export const touchListToArray = (touches: TouchList) =>
{
    const array = new Array<Touch>(touches.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < touches.length; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = touches.item(i);
    }
    return array;
};
```

Comment: `touch.identifier` is what i wanted, thanks !